# Using Auto-Cutoff to Charge Li-Ion batter

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

What are the benefits and drawbacks of using an Auto-Voltage Cutoff  when charging a Lithium Ion Battery? Will irreversible damage be done on such a battery after one charging procedure, or will damage happen over time? Here is what I mean by auto-voltage cut off (focus on the blue and black voltage curve):
[image]

V(in) is the input voltage of the an auto cutoff circuit and V(v_dc) is the output of this circuit (and is connected to the battery). For a 12 Volts Lithium Ion battery will a cut off at 9 (or 10 or 11.5 or 12, etc) Volt be detrimental? Please let me know.

Comment: This is not how you charge a Li-ion battery. Use a proper charger with constant current and constant voltage stages. Anything else is likely to destroy it sooner or later, exactly how is immaterial.

Comment: @Finbarr Will this work for lead acid batteries? When are lead acid batteries more useful / practical than Lithium Ion Batteries?

Comment: There are numerous sources online you can research this. Battery University for one.

Comment: You are stopping the charging at 9V and 10V. Batteryuiniversity.com shows that a cell is fully charged when its voltage is 4.2V and its charging current has dropped to a low amount. You probably have 3 cells that will charge to 12.6V when about 70% charged but at 9V the cells are completely dead. Ine cell is 3.2V when 0% charged, 3.7V when 50% charged and is 4.2V when fully charged but is still charging with current.

Comment: Your graph does not show Li-ion battery charging.

Answer (score 0):

The benefits of charging to a set voltage and then cutting off rather than tapering the charge current are less stress on the battery and a simpler charger circuit. The drawback is that the battery won't get a full charge.

A li-ion battery charged this way to the maximum allowed voltage (4.1 V or 4.2 V per cell) typically takes in ~80% of full charge. At this lower charge state there is less expansion of the active material and a lower oxidation rate, so it should last for more cycles and have a longer storage life. [Lipo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery) batteries may also be less likely to 'puff up'.

Some programmable chargers have a mode called 'fast charge' that cuts off when the battery reaches peak voltage. This mode is provided both to save time and increase lifespan when full capacity is not required.

If the battery is charged through a PCM (Protection Circuit Module), you might get away with simply charging it at relatively high current until the PCM activates (typically at ~4.3 V per cell). Once the PCM cuts the charge off battery voltage will drop below maximum, so it should be safe. This may reduce the lifespan a bit, but allows use of a very simple charging circuit.